# Solr Query to get the overall stats, not just the filtered ones

Tags: java, solr

I'm trying to use the Solr [StatsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent) to retrieve some information about the product prices. The problem is that if I put also a filter on these prices, like 
`stats=true&stats.field=price&fq=price:[10 TO 100]`, I only get the stats for the requested range. I would like to get price stats for all available products and not just for the filtered ones. Is that possible in a single query?

Thanks,

Comment: It seems that others are also interested in this kind of query. I found this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3177 Jira issue. Is maybe another way accomplishing this?

Comment: apply the patch attached with the jira and it should work for you.

Comment: I don't like to maintain this stuff. Would be nice if this would be already in Solr, but patching is not a good idea, especially in a multi environment.

Comment: You'll have to wait for it until this "patch" is included in the distribution. However, if it is not included...

Comment: This is the way I could express exactly want I want. I'm sure there is another way of retrieving this information from Solr, probably with some function queries. I don't really need to use the StatsComponent. Maybe somebody has another idea?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that this is possible using groups.
You can use the 
`stats=true&stats.field=price&group=true&group.query=price:[10 TO 100]` 
and leave the main `fq` with some other custom queries(or empty to get the price for all available products). The stats component will return now the stats for the results of the main `fq`, while having also the results of the `group.query` in the group component.
By the way, this can be used for a numerical slider as described in the Jira issue I posted in the comment. Things get tricky though when you want to use more than one slider.